# Docker is not importing SQL files to mysql

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

It's hours that I'm trying to solve this problem...

This is my `docker-compose`:

```
#MySQL Service
db:
  image: mysql
  container_name: db
  restart: unless-stopped
  tty: true
  ports:
    - "3307:3306"
    - "8001:3306"
  environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: your_mysql_root_password
    SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    SERVICE_NAME: mysql
  volumes:
    - ./database/dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
    - ./config/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    - ./database:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  networks:
    - app-network
```

and this is my folder

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── database
│   ├── 1-schema.sql
│   ├── 2-data.sql
│   ├── 3-user.sql
│   ├── dbdata
│   │   ├── #ib_16384_0.dblwr
│   │   ├── #ib_16384_1.dblwr
│   │   ├── #innodb_temp
│   │   ├── 4907efde64b2.pid
...
```

However, If i run

```
docker compose down
docker compose build
docker compose up
```

and log into the container, and run `mysql`, if I check the databases, there is not the one I'm importing..

What am I missing?

Comment: Workaround is `docker exec -i container_id mysql -uroot -ppassword db_name < test.sql` and then restart your container

Comment: try to mount your SQL under `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/test.sql` utilizing a volume mount

Comment: @Ashok i need this to be reproducible, and so I would like to know how to do this directly in the docker compose file

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that if there is a volume mounted to persist the data (in my case `/database/dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/`) from a previous build, the SQL files will not be run, therefore you need to delete everything inside that folder, and restart the container